# How to automatically create a link within a MENU to a specific tab?

Tags: vba, excel

Just want to start off by saying that on a rating of 1-10, my knowledge of VBA is approximately -2. I’m learning as I go and count on a lot of existing coding.

My issue, I have a workbook with two TABS:

Tab 1 = MENU (contains a listing of TABS and links to them)
Tab 2 = TEMPLATE FORM (hidden)

Within the menu, I created a button that calls a module to that allows a user to create a new TAB. When clicked, the hidden template form is made visible so it can be copied over to a new tab and then hidden again.

The user then prompted to enter the business program name, this value is carried over to a specific cell within the newly created worksheet.

The user is then prompted to enter an acronyme, this value is carried over to two places:

1) To a specific cell within the worksheet
2) Becomes the name of the TAB

This is the code I used:

```
Sub New_Prog()
Dim tmp_sheet As Worksheet
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Visible = True
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set test = ActiveSheet

Dim prog_full_name As String
prog_full_name = InputBox("What is the program's full name", "Program full name")
ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = UCase(prog_full_name)
Dim prog_acro As String
prog_acro = InputBox("What is the program's acronyme", "Program acronyme")
ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value = UCase(prog_acro)
ActiveSheet.Name = UCase(prog_acro)

Dim prog_dpt As String
prog_dpt = InputBox("What is the program's department (ESDC, TB, etc.)", "Program department")
ActiveSheet.Range("K6").Value = UCase(prog_dpt)
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Visible = False**
```

Question 1
What code should I be suing for my module to verify if a TAB with the acronyme already exists and to return an error message advising the user.

Question 2
I’m looking to have a link automatically created within a cell in the MENU TAB that links to the new TAB that was created. How do I pass the TAB name to a specific cell, into the next empty cell and make hyperlinkable to the actual TAB?

Question 3
In addition, in the MENU tab, I have a column called BUSINESS and one called CLIENT; I would like the user to select if the link should be created under the business colum, the client column or both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a 'bare-bones' solution that addresses the principles you require.  Example assumes just simple InputBoxes for user entry, the Tab names in the Menu sheet are in col menCol and the hyperlink columns are menCol+1 for Business and menCol+2 for Client.

```
Sub SOQ()
Dim wsMen As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim nextMenRow As Long, menCol As Long

Set wsMen = Sheets("Menu")
menCol = 1

usrWs = InputBox("Enter Tab Name")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If UCase(usrWs) = UCase(ws.Name) Then
            MsgBox "This Tab name already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next ws

lnk = InputBox("Create link under All (A), Business (B) or Client (C)")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = usrWs
    With wsMen
        nextMenRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, menCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(nextMenRow, menCol).Value = usrWs

            Select Case UCase(lnk)
                Case Is = "A"
                    Call createHyp(usrWs, nextMenRow, menCol + 1)
                    Call createHyp(usrWs, nextMenRow, menCol + 2)
                Case Is = "B"
                    Call createHyp(usrWs, nextMenRow, menCol + 1)
                Case Is = "C"
                    Call createHyp(usrWs, nextMenRow, menCol + 2)
            End Select

    End With
End Sub

Sub createHyp(ByVal sht As String, ByVal rw As Long, ByVal co As Long)
    With Sheets("Menu")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(rw, co), Address:="", SubAddress:=sht & "!" & Cells(1, 1).Address, TextToDisplay:="Goto " & sht
    End With
End Sub
```